# Receptor tyrosine kinases: Clarification about what is meant by stabilization of the receptor

Tags: molecular-biology, cell-biology, cell-signaling

I am reading a [journal paper](https://rupress.org/jcb/article/187/7/1101/35732/The-binding-of-NCAM-to-FGFR1-induces-a-specific). This paper focuses on how neural cell adhesion molecule (NCAM) interacts with fibroblast growth factor receptor 1 (FGFR1) and promotes its stabilization.

When FGF binds to FGFR1, the receptor gets internalized and degraded by lysosomes.

In contrast, when the soluble ectodomain of NCAM binds to FGFR1 the receptor gets internalized and recycled back to the cell surface, resulting in sustained signaling.

I asked in [another question](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/113849/what-is-meant-by-the-stabilization-of-a-receptor#:%7E:text=Stabilization%20to%20the%20postsynaptic%20membrane,processes%20can%20be%20measured%20separately.), what is meant by the stabilization of a receptor, and the response stated that it means the receptor stays in the plasma membrane and doesn't get re-internalized.

However, in the case of this paper, it seems that stabilization means that the receptor doesn't get degraded after it is endocytosed.

What exactly does 'stabilization' mean in the context of a cell-surface receptor? Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: I would look at their methods: what are they measuring? That's what they mean by stabilization.